# How to find the next/child button of a div and then click it in Power Automate Desktop with Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, ui-automation, power-automate-desktop, uibuilder

I'm currently using Power Automate Desktop. I have the problem that need to find a div with content which must contains a specific number e.g. 000000588093. when this div is found, I need to find the button below it and click it.

I'm currently using this syntax, but it not working so far

```
div[Id="Servicenummer"]:eq(1).next('button')
```

or

```
div[Id="Servicenummer"]:eq(1) > button
```

This is the html tree for this problem:

```
<div><br>
     <div id="Müller">Name: Müller</div>
     <div>ID: 1</div>
     <div>Birthday:07.07.2010</div>
     <div id="Servicenummer">Servicenummer: 000000577537</div>
     <button >Download PDF ID=1</button>
     <br><br><br>
      <div id="Seemann">Name: 
      Seemann</div>
      <div>ID: 2</div>
      <div>Geburtsdatum: 03.04.1980</div>
      <div id="Servicenummer">Servicenummer: 000000588093</div>
      <button >Download PDF ID=2</button>
   </div>
```

neither of them works. I hope you can help!

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: is that power desktop specific syntax? because that selector syntax has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: Yes! It's a slightly different syntax

Answer (score 0):

First, your html markup is invalid. Ids must be unique, you reuse `Servicenummer` as id.

The jQuery selector for your example would be:

```
$(':contains("Servicenummer: 000000577537")').next();
```

That would give you the `<button>` next to the element with text "Servicenummer: 000000577537".

Comment: I solved the problem. I needed as mentioned a unique ID, but the button was on the same level: div[Id="%ServiceNummer%"] + button

Comment: @Matthias good for you, but then it really doesnt have to do anything with jQuery. Thats a regular CSS selector, which JavaScript can use, too